# Finding Characteristic Function

Tags: stochastic-processes

Can anyone help me with this problem?
The random variable $X_n$ takes the values $\frac{k}{n}$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, each with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. Find its characteristic function and the limit as $n\to\infty$. Identify the random variable of the limit characteristic function. 
Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Rasmus: right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$E(e^{itX})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n {e^{is\frac{k}{n}}}=
\frac{1}{n}\frac{e^{\frac{is}{n}}(1-e^{is})}{1-e^{\frac{is}{n}}}\to \frac{e^{is}-1}{is}$$ as $n \to \infty$

which is cf of the uniform distribution on [0,1]

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: You should know how to calculate ${\rm E}[f(X)]$, hence, in particular, the characteristic function of $X$.

Hint 2: How can $\int_0^1 {f(x)\,{\rm d}x}$ be approximated by Riemann sum?

Hint 3: ${\rm d}x$ corresponds to which distribution?

Answer (score 2):

A bit surprised nobody mentioned this yet, but one can use a nice coupling approach here. Let $U$ denote a random variable uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. For every positive $n$, let 
$$U_n=n^{-1}\lceil nU\rceil.$$
It should be clear that each $U_n$ is distributed like $X_n$. Furthermore, $|U_n-U|<n^{-1}$ almost surely, hence $U_n\to U$ almost surely, hence $U_n\to U$ in distribution (because almost sure convergence implies convergence in distribution), hence $X_n\to U$ in distribution (because convergence in distribution does not depend on the realization of the distributions by random variables).

This may be called a coupling approach because the random variables $U_n$ are defined all at once on the same probability space (the one used to define $U$). The first chapter of *Lectures on the Coupling Method* by Torgny Lindvall explains this and some of the many other advantages of the method in different settings, see [here](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486421457.html) for a presentation of this book.